# Relation between complex analysis and harmonic function theory

Tags: cv.complex-variables, harmonic-analysis

There are some theorems in harmonic function theory that resemble results in complex analysis, like:

- Holomorphic functions and complex functions are analytic;
- Cauchy's integral formula in complex analysis and the mean value theorem in harmonic function theory;
- The principle of maximum and minimum that works for harmonic and holomophic functions.
- The real and imaginary parts of a holomorphic function are harmonic;

These results suggest that there are connections between these two areas and I would like to  ask: how can each of these theories be used to develop the other?

PS: I'm really sorry for my really bad English.

Comment: Paragraph *Connections with complex function theory* on [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_function.

Comment: There is indeed a deep and well established connection, as other
have pointed out. (In the other direction, given a harmonic function $f$, you can try to find a so called conjugate harmonic function $g$ so that $f+ig$ is holomorphic.) Unfortunately, it is hard to say
much more without writing a long essay...

Comment: I think that any book on complex analysis (or several complex variables) will discuss the connection at great length, so there is no need to write essays, long or otherwise.

Comment: See the paper _Harmonic functions from a complex analysis viewpoint_, by Sheldon Axler. (Google it to find an online version.)

Comment: I would echo some of the comments above, and suggest that a book treating harmonic function theory in the plane (or pluriharmonic function theory in higher dimensions) would address the rather vague questions you raise. Ransford's *Potential Theory in the Complex Plane *is one example I happen to know; there ought to be others.

Comment: What can the meaning of"too localized" possibly be if this question is
too localized?

Answer (score 5):

The Cauchy Riemann Equations imply that every holomorphic function satisfies Laplace's Equation and is therefore its real and imaginary components are harmonic.

You can also take a harmonic function u and construct, up to a constant, its harmonic conjugate v so that u and v satisfy the Cauchy Riemann Equations.  Thus u+iv is a holomorphic function.

These proofs can be found in just about any Complex Analysis book.  My favorite is Complex Analysis by Lars Ahlfors.

So in a sense a harmonic function is just the real component of a holomorphic function.

Comment: Do the words "simply connected" need to be mentioned somewhere?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, the construction of the harmonic conjugate of
a given harmonic function works locally, so simple connectedness 
only becomes an issue on a larger scale.